# Split the select of the same association on different fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm in the middle of developing a bike website when I stumbled on question.

I have the follow models (to simplify my description I left some models and attributes aside):

- **`model_name`:`some attributes` (example)**
- `bike`: `name`, `price`, `color` (Giant Anthem, 3999, black)
- `category`: `name` (Brakes or Shifts or Transmissions, etc)
- `component`: `name` (Shimano SLX or Shimano XT or Shimano XTR - in this case for components for the transmission category)

So the relationship of these models are the followed:

- A `bike` has many `components`
- A `component` is on many `bikes`
- A `component` belongs to a `category`
- A `category` has many `components`

Right now I've created these 3 tables and made the association: `category` has_many `components` and `component` belong_to `category`. Everything works well. Now I have to create  a jointable and use the has many through association between `bike` and `component` **BUT** the problem for me is to understand the next step after that because I don't want only one dropdown to select all components. I want to select the components divided by category. Something like this:

[image]

How can I achieve this? Hope you can help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The tricky part is that you want to split the select of the same association on different fields. You may need to handle the name of the field manually, something like this:

```
= select_tag 'bike[component_ids][]', options_from_collection_for_select(frames_category.components.all, :id, :name)
= select_tag 'bike[component_ids][]', options_from_collection_for_select(breakes_category.components.all, :id, :name)
= select_tag 'bike[component_ids][]', options_from_collection_for_select(transmissions_category.components.all, :id, :name)
= select_tag 'bike[component_ids][]', options_from_collection_for_select(tyres_category.components.all, :id, :name)
```

Note the names of the attribute `bike[components_ids][]'. The params hash on your controller will look something like:

```
params == {bike: {name: 'some name', price: '200', component_ids: [1,3,6,8]}
```

ActiveRecord should handle the assignment of the components using the `collection_singular_ids=` https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#methods-added-by-has-many-collection-singular-ids-ids

I'm not 100% sure it works on has many through but personally I wouldn't use a has many through there, "has and belong to many" seems to just fit your needs and it requires less configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My doubt was really that: how could I split the select into different fields. But please tell me, why the "HABTM" will require less configuration?  I would always have to split the select in multiple selects like you did or not? Thank you again

Comment: With "less configuration" I meant at the associations level. Instead of `has_many somethings` and then `has_many :components, throught: :somehings` you can just do `has_and_belongs_to_many :components` with no extra model. But read the guide, specially this part https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many, you sure have more context than me to decide if you can or can't use HABTM on your particular case.

Comment: Could make this a loop e.g. `<% Category.eager_load(:components).each do |category| %> <label><%= category.name %></label><%= select_tag 'bike[component_ids][]', options_from_collection_for_select(category.components, :id, :name) %><%end%>`

Comment: @engineersmnky how can I get the selected component when I'm editting that bike? Do you know?